# Unsuccessful attempt to create a folder and save mp3 file in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, storage

I have an online music player in which I dedicated a button in order to download the file. There's a "progressDialog" which works fine and shows progress of downloading file and it seems that it's really downloading my file. But after completion there's no folder nor file on my device.

I also added Write External Storage permission in my manifest.

**Here's my download class:**

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private Context context;
public static ProgressDialog progressBar;

public DownloadTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressBar.setMessage("Downloading...");
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressBar.setCancelable(true);
    progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressBar.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        fileCache();
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir() + "listening"
                + strings[1] + ".mp3");
        byte[] data = new byte[4096];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            if (fileLength > 0)
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
            outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            }
            if (inputStream != null)
                inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    progressBar.dismiss();
    if (s != null) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error while Downloading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Downloaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void fileCache() {
        File myDir = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "listening");
        if (!myDir.exists()) {
            myDir.mkdirs();
        }
}
```

}

**And here's my button's function:**

```
DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(context);
downloadTask.execute(extra.getString("link"), extra.getString("title"));
```

Comment: "But after completion there's no folder nor file on my device" -- how are you looking for it?  You are writing to what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), so you are only going to see the results via Android Studio's Device File Explorer or `adb`. "I also added Write External Storage permission in my manifest" -- that will not matter, as you are not using [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare I checked on both physical and emulator's file manager.
What do you suggest?

Comment: I mean how to change my code in order to really save files?

Comment: "What do you suggest? " -- if you are expecting your files to show up there, you need to work with what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). "I mean how to change my code in order to really save files?" -- it already is saving files (probably -- your code has been obsolete for years). It is just not saving them where you are expecting.

Comment: @CommonsWare So I'm worried if some users don't have external storage that's why I was working on internal storage. I also studied your documentation. Can you please help me with my code?

Comment: "I'm worried if some users don't have external storage" -- every modern Android device has external storage. You are probably thinking of [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). Working with storage is covered in most books and courses on Android app development. You can download older editions of one of my books [for free](https://commonsware.com/Android/4-2-free). The "Assets, Files, and Data Parsing" chapter covers more about file I/O in Android. Or, choose a more modern book.

Comment: If you prefer the documentation, [here is the starting point](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage). Switching to `getExternalFilesDir()` from `getFilesDir()` will get you most of the way there.

Comment: If you look at my codes you will see that I used 'getFilesDir()' but still no result

Comment: And that is why I suggested that you switch to `getExternalFilesDir()`.

Comment: I even used getExternalFilesDir(null) but still no difference